# How do I make use of my sql fields in vbscript to send email?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript

Below is my sql script, where in I need to display name, email and project name in the email body.

```
SELECT 
    name=p1.user_id,
    address=p1.user_email_addr,
    ( SELECT proj_nm + ', ' 
      FROM (
             select distinct 
                    user_id,
                    user_email_addr,
                    proj_nm 
             from test_table1 
             where user_enabled='Y' 
                   and user_extrl <> 'Y'
                   and datediff(dd,user_ts,getdate()) between 200 and 215 
                   and proj_src_nm <>'testproject1'
                   and proj_src_nm <>'testproject2'
                   and user_id <>'D_N_E') p2 
     WHERE p2.user_id = p1.user_id 
     ORDER BY proj_nm FOR XML PATH('')
   ) AS project 
FROM (  select distinct 
               user_id,
               user_email_addr,
               proj_nm 
        from test_table1 
        where user_enabled='Y' 
              and user_extrl <> 'Y'
              and datediff(dd,user_ts,getdate()) between 200 and 215 
              and proj_src_nm <>'testproject1'
              and proj_src_nm <>'testproject2'
              and user_id <>'D_N_E') p1 
GROUP BY user_id,user_email_addr;
```

In my vbscript file, I have the below lines of code included.

```
SendMail recordset("name"), recordset("address"), recordset("project")

objMessage.HTMLBody = strTable1 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strTable2 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strTable3
```

Where strTable1 is to display name, strTable2 to display address, strTable3 to display project from the sql. Both name and address fields are working, but project field is not working.

Comment: What does `is not working` mean? I'd expect an execution error at least if the subquery in the SELECT returned more than 1 result.  After formatting your query it becomes clear that there's a lot of duplication. Putting subqueries in the `SELECT` clause is almost never needed.

Comment: BTW `p1` already returns the project, why did you repeat the query in the SELECT clause? What were you trying to do? Why did you add that `FOR XML PATH()` in there? Did you copy some snippet from a string aggregation function? `FOR XML PATH` does *not* aggregate strings. It's only part of a function that does so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you tried to aggregate strings using part of the `FOR XML` method described [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation) but missed how it works - grouping is performed by the *outer* query. The subquery takes all rows that match the group keys and returns the results as XML that uses the empty string as the element name, resulting in one long string :

```
SELECT Name, Pets = STUFF((SELECT N', ' + Pet 
    FROM dbo.FamilyMemberPets AS p2
    WHERE p2.name = p.name 
    ORDER BY Pet
    FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 2, N'')
FROM dbo.FamilyMemberPets AS p
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name;
```

You don't have to *repeat* the query in the aggregation suqbquery. Only correlate it to the group keys. You don't have to use `DISTINCT` when you group rows either.

After a lot of simplification, the query becomses :

```
SELECT 
    name=p1.user_id,
    address=p1.user_email_addr,
    Project=STUFF(( SELECT distinct N', ' + proj_nm
                    from test_table1 as p2
                    where p2.user_id=p1.user_id and 
                          p2.user_email_addr=p1.user_email_addr
                    order by proj_nm
                    FOR XML PATH(N'')), 1, 2, N'') 
FROM test_table1 p1
where user_enabled='Y' 
      and user_extrl <> 'Y'
      and user_ts between dateadd(dd,-215,getdate()) and dateadd(dd,-200,getdate())
      and proj_src_nm <>'testproject1'
      and proj_src_nm <>'testproject2'
      and user_id <>'D_N_E'
GROUP BY user_id,user_email_addr;
```

Note the change to :

```
and user_ts between dateadd(dd,-215,getdate()) and dateadd(dd,-200,getdate())
```

When you apply a function to a field you can't use any indexes that cover it to speed up your query. It's better to *reverse* the function so that `user_ts` is between two dates in the past.

In SQL Server 2017 you can use the [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) function to aggregate strings:

```
SELECT 
    name=p1.user_id,
    address=p1.user_email_addr,
    Project=STRING_AGG(proj_nm, ',')
FROM test_table1 p1
where user_enabled='Y' 
      and user_extrl <> 'Y'
      and user_ts between dateadd(dd,-215,getdate()) and dateadd(dd,-200,getdate())
      and proj_src_nm <>'testproject1'
      and proj_src_nm <>'testproject2'
      and user_id <>'D_N_E'
GROUP BY user_id,user_email_addr;
```

Comment: Help me with the below error:
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

My SQL version is lower than 2016, so cannot make use of aggregate functions.